# How to write an image blob to a disk?

Tags: mysql, blob

I have a table that contains image BLOB field.

I want to be able to submit a query to the database and have the BLOBs written to the Windows file system.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySql: dump BLOB into local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109284/mysql-dump-blob-into-local-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) command with **INTO DUMPFILE** clause. For example -

```
SELECT
  data_column
FROM
  table1
WHERE
  id = 1
INTO DUMPFILE 'image.png';
```

From the reference: *If you use INTO DUMPFILE instead of INTO OUTFILE, MySQL writes only one row into the file, without any column or line termination and without performing any escape processing. This is useful if you want to store a BLOB value in a file.*

Comment: thanks for the answer. Where is the 'image.png' written to? I want to write it to a specific location say 'C:\DevPB\WEB\WWWRoot\PImages\image.png'

Comment: You can specify any path there; if path is not specified, then file will be stored into current directory for mysql server. Read the documentation - there is a link to SELECT statement in th answer.

Comment: SELECT
  image
FROM
  new_images
WHERE
  id = 219
INTO DUMPFILE 'c:/devpb/web/wwwroot/pimages/image.jpg';

Comment: So the next question is how to delete these files created by the DUMPFILE ?

Comment: You should do it yourself, MySQL cannot delete files.

Comment: And what happens if you wish to write multiple rows because your SELECT, say has 200 rows with 200 blobs?

Comment: @SJHowe https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html 
> If the table contains more than one row, you must also use LIMIT 1 to limit the output to a single row.

Comment: If your front end has a FileObject you can use that, for example, ASP Classic has one, so you could delete the file or move it, or make a directory for it, or what not.